# How to fix regex url pattern

Tags: regex

I need to fix my url pattern:

```
/^((http(s)?(\:\/\/)){1}(www\.)?([\w\-\.\/])*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\/?)[^\\\/#?])[^\s\b\n|]*[^\.,;:\?\!\@\^\$ -]/
```

I thought this regex was ok, but it is not working for urls like: https://xx.xx (without www). 'www' should be optional ((www.)?). Where is the bug?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the `(www\.)?` part but that parts after that.

Take a look at the `[^\\\/#?]` and the `[^\.,;:\?\!\@\^\$ -]` parts.

So a valid URL would be `https://xx.xx` plus `none of \/#?` plus `none of .,;:?!@^$_-` making the url valid if you add those, for example `https://xx.xx11`.

I do advice you to not try to create your own regex because you are missing a lot!

For example, tlds like `.amsterdam` are valid. And why are you capturing so many groups?

Your regex as an image made with https://www.debuggex.com/:
[image]

Comment: Hmm.. do you have any advice how to do it properly? I need to implement this with chrome extension and angular. Which library or just a code do it properly?

Comment: (Ron van der Heijden) , can you please tel me what is the tools you are  used to generate this helpful illustrative picture?

Comment: Thank you very much @Ron van der Heijden